# List items with bullets on top

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to have the bullet point of list items `<li>` on top of the text like in the following using CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bullets as background image:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center; /* Optional, Just for demo */
}

ul li {
  background: url(path/to/bullet.ext) center top no-repeat;
  display: inline-block; /* <-- display list items in one line */
  padding-top: 10px;     /* <-- Change this according to the image size */
  /* Or: */
  /* padding: 10px 5px 0;     */
  /*          top  r&l bottom */
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/usaKaSA/5/edit)**

Comment: is it possible to add a line that goes accros the bullets? using and image or a border?

Comment: @onlymushu You're welcome. You could use [multiple background-image](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/), Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/usaKaSA/6/edit

Comment: Another option would be using `::after` or `::before` pseudo elements on lists items to add another background image which support IE8 too: http://jsbin.com/usaKaSA/12/edit

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for, but I'm thinking on putting my line in another div that will contain my ul - li. thanks again Hashem

Comment: @onlymushu If you could provide an image I can help. but if you meant across the bullet itself, change the background position to achieve that: http://jsbin.com/usaKaSA/15/edit