# vertical-align does not align the list-style-image with the text

Tags: html, css

I have a list setup in html as follows:

```
<ul id="remove">
<li id="rm_txt_1" onClick="remove_1();">Remove </li>
</ul>


<ul id="move">
<li id="mv_txt_1" onClick="position();">Move Down</li>
</ul>
```

Styled with the following css codes:

```
#remove{
    list-style-image:url(../images/remove.fw.png);
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;}

#move{
    list-style-image:url(../images/mvdown.fw.png);
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-top:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;}

#rm_txt_1, #mv_txt_1{
    padding-left:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:14px;
    vertical-align:middle;}
```

Though I have considered "vertical-align:middle;" foe all "ul" and "li"s the result looks awkward as below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing vertical-align:middle; from images?

Comment: try to include line-height;

Comment: It's not possible to control the position of `list-style-image`. One option would be [using `background-image`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452697/list-items-with-bullets-on-top/18452737#18452737) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line-height property to your css code for #remove and #move, with the height of your images.

Answer (score 0):

Make your text bigger so it has the same height as your image.

OR
Give it a background image and position it with padding.

```
li{    
background: url(../images/remove.fw.png)
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

edit: line-height will push your text down, not up.

Answer (score 0):

You're aligning middle but you've also got your padding pushing it further to the right. Remove your padding and see if that helps.